# Find linear price function from a point

Tags: functions, economics, slope

I have to do a simple managerial economics exercise.

I know that a firm sells $Q=16000$ units at a price of $P=1672$.

Moreover, I know that

- it will sell 18% more units if the firm decrease the price by 20%
- it will sell 10% less units if the firm increase the price by 5%

I need to find the linear price function $P(Q)$.

I guess I need to find the price function using my initial point $(Q,P)=(16000,1672)$ and the price elasticity in some point.

But from the information about how the number of units sold will change due to a change in price, I obtain two different price elasticities.

- elasticity1 = 18%/(-20%) = -0.9
- elasticity2 = -10%/5% = -2

Am I doing it correctly?

I'm really not sure if I'm doing it correctly, because to me it seems that I can simply get 3 points $(Q1,P1)=(16000,1672)$, $(Q2,P2)=(16000 \cdot 1.18,1672 \cdot 0.8)$, and $(Q3,P3)=(16000 \cdot 0.9,1672 \cdot 1.05)$. But using these 3 points, the price function is not linear, so I guess I need to do something else.

Comment: What is the word for word question ?

Comment: "The company sells the item for $1,672 for which they in 2015 sold 16,000 units. Because of competition, they expect that if they increase their current price by 5%, the sales will drop by 10%, whereas they expect that if they raise the price by 20%, the sales will increase by 18%.

Now calculate the price function where Q is assumed to be the sale per year."